# How to cut some files from earlier commits in Git?

Tags: git

what I've done:

```
git clone ssh://... ...
git commit
...
git commit
```

but there was a file (something secret ;) which I should *never* push.
Normally, i would have done something like

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

to undo the last one, but it was too many commits ago

or:

```
git diff REV > /file.patch
```

to apply it on the top of remote/master, but I want to keep current commits

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history

Comment: And this too: http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: if you have pushed, there is no way to to keep you current commits as is, and try to fix as in the previous two comments, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```bsh
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
```

[**ref**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: Note that, as with all suggestions on this Q&A, the commit IDs will be changed from the first commit to be changed; so if you're sharing history with others, you'll need to co-ordinate with others to take your new history.